# How google searches show result of wordpress posts?

Tags: wordpress

As we know wordpress stores its post and pages in database not in a physical page then how it is possible by google to show result from the postswhich doesnot exist physically.
Also if we do the same will it work or not?
Please do make me clear.

Comment: Read these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short-answer:

- A web-address is ultimately just a [string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)) (a piece of text) given to a web-server which it can interpret and act-on **any way it likes**.
- It **can** simply map that string to a file-system path and see if it matches a file on disk and return that file to the website visitor.
- **But** it can also instead use that string to do something completely different - such as looking it up in a database and then returning database content.
- A web-server is not just (old-school) servers like Apache and IIS that default to serving filesystem content - but it also includes server-side programs like PHP scripts, Node.js applications, and so on.

### Step-by-step explanation:

1. A website visitor (human's web-browser, search engine spider, a bot, etc) requests `GET http://example.wordpress.com/2019/10/12/lorem-ipsum`
2. The TCP packet with the request reaches physical computers owned or operated by Wordpress.com.

   - (This answer will ignore complications like network-load-balancing, application-level routing, HTTP reverse-proxies, and so on.)
3. The physical computer's operating system routes that network packet to the "outer" webserver software, this is like Apache or nginx.
4. Apache or nginx only looks at the `GET` and `2019/10/12/lorem-ipsum` part of the request, these are the Method and Path components of the request respectively.
5. **If** the "outer" web-server is configured to map the website's root with some filesystem directory, then it will look to see if (by default) `/var/www` (the default root for Apache on Linux) or `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` (the default root for IIS on Windows) contains a file named `lorem-ipsum` exists in `/var/www/2019/10/12` (or `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\2019\10\12\lorem-ipsum` on Windows).

   - But **Wordpress.com does not do this**.
   - Most modern web-applications built today also do not do this, because exposing raw files directly to the internet generally isn't a good idea (but it's still okay for "static file websites", of course).
6. Instead, WordPress.com is specifically configured to pass the entire `2019/10/12/lorem-ipsum` string into `php.exe` along with the path to the entrypoint script file of WordPress.com's namesake PHP web-application.

   - This is actually [just WordPress' `index.php` file](https://themeisle.com/blog/wordpress-core-files/) - however remember that it is invoked using a variety of special techniques (using `PATH_INFO`) which is why you don't see `index.php` inside URIs like `example.wordpress.com/index.php/2019/10/12/lorem-ipsum`.
7. And then `php.exe` runs through the script, which then looks-up `2019/10/12/lorem-ipsum` in a database, then retrieves the content, builds and renders the page as HTML and then returns the rendered HTML to the website visitor from step 1.

### Better answer:

Think more *abstractly* and challenge your assumptions:

- URLs do not point to a web-pages. They actually point to "resources".
- A "resource" is not necessarily a web-page. A resource is a representation of some "thing".

  - A web-page, too, can itself be a representation of some "thing".
- A web-page is not necessarily a static HTML file on-disk.

  - A web-page can be generated dynamically on-the-fly by server-side software like PHP, NodeJS ASP.NET, Java/JSP/Servlets, CGI (archaic), and so on.

In WordPress' case:

- The URL `http://example.wordpress.com/2019/10/12/lorem-ipsum` points to a WordPress article.

  - But a WordPress article can be represented in different ways - such as a HTML web-page (as in this example), but it could also be represented as a JSON blob or XML blob (for consumption by other computer programs).
  - That WordPress article could also be represented as a part of another resource, such as a link when you request all articles published in October 2019 (by getting `http://example.wordpress.com/2019/10`).